# $\bot$ operator for integers?

Tags: notation

Quote from a proof on page 9 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.3356&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> Let $\hat{w}$ be the $\mathbf{(s[j] \bot 1)st}$ write by $p_i$. (emphasis mine)

$s[j]$ is an integer. My initial guess was that this was typo/misprint and either $+$ or $-$ was intended, but I can't seem to make sense of the proof assuming $\bot$ is either of those, so I'm wondering if there's some perhaps meaning of $x \bot y$ for integers $x,y$ that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I agree, probably $+$.  A sign that it was typeset by a real typist, and not the author.

Comment: $x \bot y$ sometimes means that $x, y$ are co-prime, but I don't see sense for it here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at page 7 (the algorithm), $\bot$ is used as a symbol for undefined. This is confirmed on page 4 ('...$v=\bot$. That is a read with no write must return *the initial value*'). This leads me to assume the two occurences of $s[j]\bot 1$ are a typo and meant to say $s[j]+1$.